# Google Sheet Script to check landing pages for phrases like 'out of stock'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering how to create a Google docs script to check a list of landing pages for phrases like "oos" , "out of stock" , "currently unavailable", and etc. I know there are a few for Google Ads, but I need it to be out of Google Docs.

Comment: What do you mean by check landing pages? can you please expound? give some data or at least show what your data looks like.

Comment: Also show some expected output.

Comment: I'm assuming since your tag included sheets and not document, you are referring to Spreadsheets and not Documents. I modified your title and added google-apps-script as tag. Also, feel free to check the solution below if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UrlFetchApp.fetch` to check the contents of the site and use `match` to check if it matches with your keywords.

#### Code:

```
function importxml2(url) {
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var regex = /( oos )|(out of stock)|(currently unavailable)/gi;
  if (content.match(regex))
    return "pattern found";
  return "pattern not found"
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Just call the function `importxml2` and pass as parameter the cell containing the link.
- It checks the actual content of the site (including scripts and anything you see in the page source, so be careful with the patterns you use)

#### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String))
- [match](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp)